# How does InputVerifier prevent losing focus

Tags: java, focus, components, inputverifier

I looked at the InputVerifier class and all I see are booleans. I looked around a bit more (`FocusEvent`, `requestFocus()`, `focusLost`)  and I still don't see the particular event that prevents the other `Component` from gaining focus. I've also looked at all the elements of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) and I still don't see it!

I know of a good way to verify the component that would gain focus with `FocusEvent.getOppositeComponent()`,  I just don't know how to manually prevent the other component from gaining focus.

No flags please.